# How to make conditional validate with Yup with computed value in conditional vue 3 typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, yup

How to make conditional validate with Yup with computed value in conditional?
There is variable `const isVerifiedPhone = computed<boolean>(() => !!authStore.profile?.phone);`

There is validation

```
const { values, errors, submit } = useForm(
  yup.object({
    phone: yup
      .string()
      .default('')
      .required('Введите номер телефона')
      .length(10, 'Номер телефона должен включать 10 цифр'),

    email: isVerifiedPhone.value
      ? yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('').required('Введите имя')
      : yup.string().email('Введите Email').default(''),
  }),
  {
    defaultValues: {
      phone: userPhone.value,
      email: userEmail.value,
    },
  },
);
```

With this structure condition isVerifiedPhone.value doesnt update inside `useForm`

I tried that way

```
email: yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('').when(isVerifiedPhone.value, {
is: true, 
then:  yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('').required('Введите имя'),
otherwise:  yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('')
})
```

But I have error into property `is`

And I tried that way

```
email: yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('').when([], {
is: () => isVerifiedPhone.value, 
then:  yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('').required('Введите имя'),
otherwise:  yup.string().email('Введите Email').default('')
})
```

and also have a error into property `is`

How I can do this?
I need that my email field will required if only isVerifiedPhone.value === true
I found only ways conditional validate with fileds inside form, but this is not I need

Comment: "I have error into property is" - what error?

Answer (score -2):

To achieve conditional validation with a computed value in Vue 3 with TypeScript using Yup, you can use a slightly different approach. Instead of using the .when() method directly with the computed property, you can create a custom validation function that checks the value of isVerifiedPhone and returns the appropriate schema.

Here's how you can do it:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.3.2/vue.global.min.js"></script>
import { computed } from 'vue';
import * as yup from 'yup';
import { useForm } from 'vee-validate'; // Assuming you are using vee-validate for form handling

// Example authStore and user data for demonstration
const authStore = {
  profile: {
    phone: '1234567890',
  },
};
const userPhone = computed(() => authStore.profile.phone);
const userEmail = computed(() => '');

const isVerifiedPhone = computed<boolean>(() => !!authStore.profile?.phone);

// Custom validation function
function emailValidation() {
  return isVerifiedPhone.value
    ? yup.string().email('Введите Email').required('Введите имя')
    : yup.string().email('Введите Email');
}

// Form validation schema
const validationSchema = yup.object({
  phone: yup
    .string()
    .required('Введите номер телефона')
    .length(10, 'Номер телефона должен включать 10 цифр'),
  email: emailValidation(),
});

// useForm hook
const { values, errors, submit } = useForm({
  validationSchema,
  initialValues: {
    phone: userPhone.value,
    email: userEmail.value,
  },
});
```

the emailValidation function returns the appropriate Yup schema based on the value of isVerifiedPhone. This way, the validation schema for the email field is dynamically determined by the computed property.